# Show products minimum quantity allowed in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

How to show products minimum quantity allowed on cart page. For list and view pages I used this code

```
<?php
$productQuantity = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")->loadByProduct($_product->getId()); 
$i = $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty();
?>
```

But this code is not working in cart page default.phtml, can someone please help me with correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cart page, on the cart item object you can do this

```
$minSaleQty = $_item->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
```

Comment: This didn't work, do I need to place this code in default.phtml only or anyother?

Comment: yes. In the default.phtml. but be careful. the variable name might be `$_item`.